# Eclipse unable to generates classes while using AWS SWF

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

I am following hello world application of Amazon Web Services Simple Workflow Service. According to description @Activities annotation should have been able to generate two classes GreeterActivitiesClient and GreeterActivitiesClientImpl. But these classes has not been generated.

I have Enable annotation processing in project properties. I am using Eclipse Mars with Jdk 1.8. I have also installed AWS toolkit for eclipse, aspectj.

Can someone see where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some versions of Eclipse, (notably Mars and Neon), may fail to fetch the latest artifacts due to a bug in old versions of the Oomph plugin. To work around this issue:

1. Make sure that you’re using https://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/site.xml as the AWS Toolkit for Eclipse update site.
2. Delete the ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.oomph.p2/cache/ directory to remove cached content.
3. Install the latest version of Oomph (Eclipse Installer).

Reference: [Set up the Toolkit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/setup-install.html)

Comment: I'm having the same issue even after following the steps above.